# combine_tessdata: command not found

Tags: ocr, tesseract, training-data

I have installed tesseract (linux mint) and with `tesseract -v` command I get

```
tesseract 3.03
 leptonica-1.70
  libgif 4.1.6(?) : libjpeg 8d : libpng 1.2.50 : libtiff 4.0.3 : zlib 1.2.8 : webp 0.4.0
```

However, when I run the following command

```
combine_tessdata -u /usr/share/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/tur.traineddata /home/hp/tur.
```

I get.

> combine_tessdata: command not found

What do I need to run combine_tessdata command? I think it should come with tesseract installation or do I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved. I had installed tesseract using software manager of linux/mint. In that way I could use tesseract command but not combine_tessdata. I removed all things related with tesseract that I  installed using software manager.

Then I downloaded the source of tesseract, compiled and able to use combine_tessdata finally.

If you do not remove previously installed tesseract library it passess "command not found" error but then it gets "segmentation fault error".